# How to use HTTP Boot for VMWare VM UEFI client

Tags: vmware-esxi, https, uefi

I have a VMWare VM (ESXi 6.5, VM version 13) that I want to image over the network. For the past several years we have been using (with much success) a TFTP server containing a PXE image. Now I want to move to using UEFI and have the UEFI client get the image using HTTPS.

1. On the VMWare VM I changed "Boot Options|Firmware" from "BIOS" to "EFI".
2. Added an HTTPS endpoint to the image server so that the UEFI client can download the UEFI image (`https://example.com/ldlinux.e64`).
3. Changed the DHCP setting for the client from sending "filename" with value "pxeclient.0" to instead send `https://example.com/ldlinux.e64`.

When I boot the VM the EFI boot manager starts but I see this error:

```
_unsuccessful.bell (Unsupported option) 0:0)
PXE-E23: Client received TFTP error from server.inux.64
```

Sniffing the network I see that UEFI client is still trying to access the TFTP service rather than the HTTPS service. What do I need to do to convince the UEFI client to download the iamge pointed to by the URL rather than continuing to use TFTP?

**UPDATE**: Sniffing for the DHCP traffic on our DHCP server I see that the VM guest is sending a DHCP request with Option 60, Vendor Class ID set to `PXEClient:Arch:...`. The UEFI specification for HTTP Boot says that this value should be `HTTPClient:Arch:...`. Thus, the issue boils down to how to get the VM guest system to send its DHCP request with Option 60 set to "HTTPClient".

Comment: What version of `esxi` are you using?

Comment: ESXi 6.5, VM version 13 (added to question).

Comment: After looking at the VMware 7 UEFI blob, I am fairly certain that VMware currently does not support HTTP installation of guest OSes.

Answer (score 0):

you have several issues;

1. VMware UEFI does not support HTTP Boot
2. If it would you are pointing to boot `ldlinux`.e64 which is not a PE UEFI application but an ELF component of Pxelinux. it will never boot.

Finally how much faster do you think an HTTP boot capture will be compared with a regular PXE capture where only the initial Boot.wim is TFTP transfer with let say windowsize=16 and then a MS share for the bulk of the capture? the gain is not much; make it simple.